# Rebuild RST Fake RAID on dual boot system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, raid, intel-rst, dualboot

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a second OS on a computer which had Windows 7 already installed. The computer had an Intel RST FakeRAID level 5. After a good deal of messing around, I finally followed the instructions in the top answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m). This worked fine... until one of my hard drives failed.

I replaced the drive with a drive from a different brand (but the same size as the old drive), and booted into Windows, where I rebuilt the RAID volume with Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

Now Windows boots and functions perfectly fine, but Ubuntu drops to a busybox initramfs terminal, and says that fsck found errors and needed to be run manually.

According to [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005769/technologies.html), mdadm is supposed to be able to handle Intel RST. So why doesn't the rebuild work for both operating systems? What is the correct way to rebuild a Fake RAID on a dual boot system?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running fsck on the last partition. This seems to have solved the problem (although I still don't know how the filesystem got corrupted in the first place).